# Unable to launch specific module properly

Tags: python

I am installing [specific module](https://github.com/GTB3NW/SteamTradingServices) from Github, but i am having problems using it's functions.

These are steps i took to install module:

1. Downloaded the zip file and unzipped it normally.
2. Launched `setup.py` with `install` option. (`python setup.py install`)
3. The module didn't have any documentation, so i checked `setup.py` and it's name was "Exchange".
4. I tried importing the module ( `import Exchange` ) and it worked.
5. Now since i couldn't find any documentation, i viewed `exchange.py` from github ( /Exchange/exchange.py ).
6. I tried using one of the functions, didn't work.

Then i realized that i was in folder file, so:

1. i imported `exchange.py` itself ( `from Exchange import exchange`).
2. Now from `exchange.py` i imported `Exchange` class (`from Exchange.exchange import Exchange` ).
3. I tried to call the class, (`Exchange`), but i needed to specify 7 arguments for `__init__`.

---

and again, i realized that i needed to launch the `exchange.py` itself, so i would have no problems, this is where i got stuck, i couldn't launch it.

How could i launch the module properly? Am i right that i need to start from `exchange.py`? If so how could i launch it? If not then what's the proper entry point?

Comment: Looks like it declared a console script entry point `"trade-exchange=Exchange.exchange:main",`, so if you had installed it you can just run it by calling `trade-exchange` from your shell.

Comment: @metatoaster I am sorry i could not understand, should i try `trade-exchange` from Python shell?, It would give me that it is not defined...

Comment: Do it from the standard command line (`bash`, `sh`, `csh`, or `cmd` if you are on Windows).

Comment: @metatoaster got error `-bash: trade-exchange: command not found`, i tried adding `SteamTradingServices-master/Exchange` to path but didn't work.

Comment: FIXED PROBLEM! tried importing main from `Exchange.exchange` ( `from Exchange.exchange import main` ) and then called it ( `Main()` )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the problem, Thanks to @metatoaster.

The entry of module, is `main` function from `exchange.py`, after calling it, module will be started.

So to start application, you need to import `exchange.py` from Exchange package, and from `exchange.py`, import and call `main` function.

1. `from Exchange.exchange import main`
2. `main()`